# 'patternTransform' : 'rotate(140)' not working in safari

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, safari

patternTransform 'rotate()' is not working as expected in safari browser as it is working in chrome (color is getting changed) .

```
.attr('patternTransform','rotate(140)')
```

HERE is my jsfiddle link

```
https://jsfiddle.net/shubham_singh/v24LwmqL/
```

line number 147 (.attr('patternTransform','rotate(140)'))

if i comment this line the colors are coming correctly in both browsers

[This image shows how this SVG chart looks in chrome browser in high resolution iMac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVfuk.png)

[This image shows how this SVG chart looks in safari browser in high resolution iMac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZNGO.png)

Please help!!!

Comment: Works fine, looks identical on my Mac with Safari 10.1.1. Any particular version you're testing with?

Comment: The resolution was 4096X2304

Comment: I mean what version of Safari are you having an issue with?

Comment: Mac resolution was 4096X2304
Safari Version : 10.1.2 .
In my mac it was coming correct but iMac with above specification the difference was coming . 
I figured out the issue it was with Hex Color Codes . only first three letters were picked by safari like #FFC830 was automatically converted to #000FFC.  so when i give color code in rgba format it works fine.

Comment: That sounds like a weird bug, I'm glad you sorted it. You might want to answer your own question with the solution.

Comment: I have struggled for two days and today i discussed with design team then we figured out the issue and solved it. by the ways thanks